# Footer DIV comes up on Container DIV having two children DIVs

Tags: html, layout

**Container : relative positioned.** Have two child div **left** and **right column** having 60% and 30% width of container.

**Left child : absolute positioned .** Top:0; Left:0; width: 60%; 
**Right child : absolute positioned .** Top:0; right:0; width: 30%;

**Footer: Relative positioned.**

But footer comes up. Code Given below. Visit the [following code LIVE here](http://tutorial.webdesignershouse.com/example-codes/css-layout-flaw-1.html)
**can anyone tell me whats wrong in the following code, I think technically all correct.**

```
<style type="text/css">
    #container {
    position: relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    background: #C63;
    padding: 10px;
    height:auto;
}

#leftCol {
    position: absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    background: #e8f6fe;
    width: 60%;
}

#rightCol {
    position: absolute;
    top:10px;
    right:10px;
    width:30%;
    background: #aafed6;
    }

.box {
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
    background:#F39;
     }

</style>

  <div id="container">

  <div id="leftCol">
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus varius eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Phasellus varius eleifend.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus varius eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Phasellus varius eleifend.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus varius eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Phasellus varius eleifend.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus varius eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Phasellus varius eleifend.</p>
   </div>

<div id="rightCol"> 
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus varius eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Phasellus varius eleifend.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus varius eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Phasellus varius eleifend.</p>

    </div>

 </div>

 <div class="box">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus varius eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Phasellus varius eleifend.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus varius eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Phasellus varius eleifend.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus varius eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Phasellus varius eleifend.</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to mention the **height** of the **#container** div. Like this

```
#container {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #CC6633;
  height: 240px; // mention height
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: // is not valid in css only in javacript

Comment: Oh come on, it was intended to make **more clear** to the asker about the changed property. I know it's only valid in JS.

Answer (score 0):

change **margin 0 auto** to `margin: 0 auto 228px;`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KwB5r/

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    /*margin:0 auto;*/
    margin: 0 auto 228px;
    width: 1000px;
    background: #C63;
    padding: 10px;
    height:auto;
}
```

or set the `heigth` of you container to `228px` for example
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should leave the `position: absolute` rule from the `<div>` tags that are inside `<div id="container">`. And also should add the rule `display: inline-block;` to the right and left `<div>` tags:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #container {
    position: relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    background: #C63;
    padding: 10px;
    height:auto;
    }
    #leftCol {
    display: inline-block;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    background: #e8f6fe;
    width: 60%;

    }
    #rightCol {
    display: inline-block;
    top:10px;
    right:10px;
    width:30%;
    background: #aafed6;
    }

    .box {
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
    background:#F39;
    }
    </style>

    <div id="container">
    <div id="leftCol">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus varius eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Phasellus varius eleifend.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus varius eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Phasellus varius eleifend.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus varius eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Phasellus varius eleifend.</p>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus varius eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Phasellus varius eleifend.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="rightCol"> 
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus varius eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Phasellus varius eleifend.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus varius eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Phasellus varius eleifend.</p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus varius eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Phasellus varius eleifend.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus varius eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Phasellus varius eleifend.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus varius eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Phasellus varius eleifend.</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi, You are almost correct, but not 100% , because #rightCol should be placed top:10, right:10 inside container DIV.

Comment: But I have added position: absolute; inside #rightCol style in your code mentioned above that places the rightcol DIV in proper position, but position: absolute; should not be applied to both DIV  #rightCol and #leftCol, if you do that the DIV container will shrink.

Comment: My question was why this CONTAINER shrinks and it just came into my mind.. that right and leftcol child DIVS has content so they have some height which is not explicitly defined. But when they becomes abosultely postions they flies out from document flow.. so container dont get their height so.. container shrinks.. What you say ?

Comment: When using `position: absolute;` this content is positioned regardless of the tag(s) position. So that's why your footer is flowing, because it is not finding anything above, but the `position: absolute;` tag, which is not considered.